# Не могу развернуть на OpenServer редакцию битрикс

Tags: битрикс, php8

Пытаюсь развернуть демо битрикса на OpenServer, все настроено как надо, но на моменте с установкой выскакивают ошибки модулей, по итогу загрузка просто зависает и дальше ничего не происходит.

Comment: Приведите ваш код, чтобы было от чего отталкиваться тем, кто захочет помочь :)

Comment: Какой код, если я его даже развернуть не могу. Просто может кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой.

Стоит php 8.1, апач соответствует, просто выдает ошибки установки модуля и зависает. Качаю bitrixsetup с официального сайта.